# Change phase in sine function

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I need some help with mathematics in my Unity game. Here is the concept:
Ball moves up and down using sine function (blue line). In any moment of time player may want to press space bar and change direction of ball according to red line. As example, I've chosen pi/4.

- The ball must save it's position on y axis
- it must invert it's vertical motion.

So the change should be smooth, I think, with no unnatural jumps.

Plot:

[image]

Here is my class:

```
public class GoForward : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.1f; // speed of forward motion
    public float amplitude = 5f; // strength of vertical motion
    public float frequency = 5f; // width of spikes of vertical motion

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        float phase = 0f; // phase displacement

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // find phase displacement here
        }

        // apply new position to the ball
        float xpos = transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float ypos = amplitude * Mathf.Sin (frequency * Time.time + phase);
        transform.position = new Vector3 (xpos, ypos, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Of course, I think solution is simpliest, but my mind can't concentrate. *So I need your help, guys.*

**I need to find phase displacement in any moment of time, so that all my conditions must hold.**

Thanks!

Solution found. Thank all of you a lot for help!

Comment: Do you have an actual question?  There is no question mark anywhere to be seen.  What is actually wrong with your code that you need help with?

Comment: JK, "I need to find phase displacement in any moment of time, so that all my conditions must hold." So my question is: what is the value of phase in any moment of time? I need formula, so I can place it in my code. Or, if you've understood what I want and if you have much better concept of achieving same results: please, share it with me.

Comment: first I kind of wonder why you are using sin instead of a simple parabola instead but well does not matter - if you want it to *decent* at once you cannot have a smooth effect - but if I get you right you just want the same y at the *other side of the hill* right? The sin has it's max at 0.5Pi so it's rather easy: you are looking for `Pi - t` (... that is your phase is dependet on `t`!) ... and yes this will only be good for the positive part of the sin (0 <= `t` < Pi)

Comment: Thanks, @CarstenKönig! I've tried out Pi - t, but as you say it holds only in some cases. I should solve some equations, right? So, blue line stands for f(x) = sin(x + p_1), where p_1 is an any starting phase. Red line stand for g(x) = sin(x + p_2). Right? I need p_2. y's must be equal, so f(x) = g(x), in other words sin(x + p_1) = sin(x + p_2), right? This is the first equation. I need to invert motion, so derivatives must be with different signs. So we have sin'(x + p_1) >= sin'(x + p_2), f(x) >= 0; and  sin'(x + p_1) < sin'(x + p_2), f(x) < 0; right?

Comment: There are not many points where `sin` has the same value (in the interval [0..2pi] - it's *very* periodic though) - IMO you don't need to know anything about it's derivative, the phase just translates the sin along the x-axis, if you do nothing more you get the naive `sin(x) = sin(x+2pi)` and the pair of values I gave you together with another pair around `3/2 * pi`

Comment: Another very easy trick could be to get just **invert** time (factor `-1.0` or `1.0` inside your `sin`) whenever you hit space

Comment: @CarstenKönig I've checked out time invertion - doesn't work. But I also add pi/2 and this method works fine in two cases: y > 0, y' < 0; and y < 0, y' > 0; Maybe I should add some conditions and if's? I want  kinda universal formula, don't want if's in my code.

Comment: if you invert the time you have to "remember" the phase (it's just the current time) ... I don't know why this should not work to be honest ... just play a bit with it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given time `Time.time` of the first half phase, the distance to the sine maximum is

```
dist = Pi/2 - frequency * Time.time
```

You need to offset the curve by twice the distance (up the hill, then down the same amount). So you need:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
{
    phase = Pi - 2 * frequency * Time.time - oldPhase;
}
```

This also works for the second half phase.